If a graph is 1-factoreable, then it has no cut vertex.
I'm trying to prove the statement: if a graph $G$ is 1-factorable, then $G$ has no cut vertex.
Assuming $G$ has a cut vertex, let be $v\in V(G)$ a cut vertex of $G$. Then the connected components of $G-v$ are greater than the components of $G$.
Since $G$ is 1-factorable, let's call $H_1,H_2,\ldots,H_r$ the 1-factors of $G$ such that $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^rE(H_i)=E(G)$.  I'm sure there is something to do with how many vertices we have in $H_1-v$ and $H_2-v$ and such, related to the parity, that leads me to a contradiction. Maybe there's another thing to consider that lead us to an absurd.
I'm stuck from the start, so any hint would be appreciated.

Parity is a good guess. $G$ must have an even number of vertices, so cutting a cut vertex $v$ must leave an odd order connected component $C$. If we pick any edge from $v$ to any other connected component, it must belong to a $1$-factor $H$. But then $C \cap H$ is a $1$-factor of $C$, which would contradict $C$ having odd order.

Good. And the graph doesn't have to be $1$-factorable, it's enough that each edge belongs to a $1$-factor, right?

@user14111 Yes, that makes sense.
